# Applying Angular.js FilterBy to nested json attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I have been experimenting with angular.js as a way of handling sortable and searchable lists of data.

Used this RailsCast to get started http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs

And then went through the example of filters here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Was awestruck when I had something running in minutes sorting and filtering. I therefore appear to have an ideal approach to presenting tabular data that is sortable and searchable by filtering across every column...

Until I realised that the filter does not appear to work on json nested attrbutes addressed using '.' notation e.g. my clients all  have an owner and I want to display their email address and sort and sift by this field - key parts of my code look like this.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="client in clients | orderBy:sort_by:reverse | filter:search">
  <tr>
     <td>{{name}}</td>
     <td>{{owner.email}}</td>
  <tr>

<input ng-model="search.name">
<input ng-model="search.owner.email">
```

The owner.email is rendered and can be sorted but it won't filter. I have a workaround of :only allowing one attribute per :include association and searching on the association e.g. search.owner filters on the owner's email because that's all I have allowed into the json. This feels like a hack. There must be properly elegant way of doing this. What is it?

Comment: Define your own [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters).  Your custom filter can filter based on `search.owner.email` or whatever other criteria/input you want.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think the custom filter will work, but it isn't as elegant as just being able to utilise the filter:search for any column/attribute just by making a bound input for the column/attribute to filter by - which allows me to easily automate the generation using arrays and blocks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, you'll probably have to use a [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters).  A custom filter can filter based on `search.owner.email` or whatever other criteria/input you want.